# angular2 index.html doesn't show rendered template

Tags: html, tomcat, intellij-idea, angular

I have a tomcat server project in intellij.

I have created in this project a `client` folder.

It contains an `angular2` index.html template.

I run the tomcat from intellij and it's hosted with port 8880

Then I try to access `localhost:8880/../client/index.html` (simplified the path)

this is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ng2</title>

  {{#unless environment.production}}
  <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  {{/unless}}
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    {{#each scripts.polyfills}}
    <script src="{{.}}"></script>
    {{/each}}
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

but I see this content:

```
{{#unless environment.production}} {{/unless}} Loading... {{#each scripts.polyfills}} {{/each}}
```

if i use npm start and navigate to `localhost:4800` I see the html as I expect it.

How can I host the server and client both on port `8880` so the client can post to the server with the same port?

Comment: As your question, you have a java backend and angular front-end right? FE builds with npm. Your trying to host both ends with tomcat. Am I correct?

Comment: yes. is there a way to do so?

Comment: Are you using any java framework??

Comment: for backend i'm using jersy and java

Comment: you can try on of these. :) https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin , https://github.com/mulesoft/npm-maven-plugin